# Align strings over a common character

Tags: python, string, format, text-alignment

I am looking for a simple, pythonic way of doing this with the minimum calculations and loops.

I have a bunch of strings, such as:

```
1 + 2 = 3

2*6 + 13 = 25
```

What I would like to print at the screen is:

```
xxx1 + 2 = 3

2*6 + 13 = 25
```

(where the `x` are actually spaces, but I could not figure out how to show it with this editor)

I am aware of string formatting with left and right align but this imply for each string to compute the number of spaces to add, convert it into a string, and inject this into the string alignment formatter, which seems complex.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: show your code and output. also, show us some string data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, this may work:

```
lst = [
'1 + 2 = 3',
'2*6 + 13 = 25',
'2*6 = 12',
'2 = 12 - 10'
]

mxleft = max([e.index('=') for e in lst])

l2 = [e.split('=')[0].rjust(mxleft) + '=' + e.split('=')[1] for e in lst]

print('\n'.join(l2))
```

Output

```
   1 + 2 = 3
2*6 + 13 = 25
     2*6 = 12
       2 = 12 - 10
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly, rjust was the method I was missing

Answer (score 0):

if you know the maximum size of string before the equal signal you can split the string int the signal and then joint it using the format method (https://pyformat.info/). If you don't know you will have to check for it first and the best way to do this depends on how you are storing your strings.

```
string = '1+4+3=2'
split = string.split('=')

new_string = '{:>10}={}'.format(*split)
```